# Update form while it is hidden while Desktop Composition is enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint

I'm trying to change my form appearance when it is hidden. And then make it visible.

```
private void HideLabelAndShowForm()
{
    label1.Hide();
    Invalidate(true);
    Update();
    // thinking we now have no label on the form?
    Show();
    // no! the label is still visible!
    // and gets hidden after a moment
}
```

Why does the form get redrawn only after the previous content (with visible label) is displayed for a moment? Any workaround?

**Update**

1. **This only happens when Desktop Composition is enabled** (I use Windows 7).
2. Removing Invalidate and Update doesn't help
3. Method is called from a UI thread
4. Adding Thread.Sleep and Application.DoEvents everywhere doesn't help
5. Calling Show after a delay from a separate thread (using Invoke) doesn't help

Comment: Do you really need Invalidate(true) and Update() calls?

Comment: I thought these steps force form to redraw itself. But they don't.

Comment: According to @Tigran, why you need the Invalidate(true) and Update() here, do you tried by putting some delay like Thread.Sleep after label1.Hide()?

Comment: How is this method getting invoked?  UI components can only be interacted with by the thread that created them.

Comment: Tried to put Thread.Sleep everywhere. But the form is only refreshed after the previous content is shown. I even tried to invoke Show after a delay (using a separate thread) -  but this simply doesn't matter

Comment: This method is invoked on a UI thread:Invoke(new MethodInvoker(HideLabelAndShowForm));

Comment: Tried this code here. Does exactly what is expected: label1 becomes invisible when label1.Hide() is called and then form becomes visible without lable1 when this.Show() is called.

Comment: Josh, I've disabled Desktop composition, and now it really hides label1 before showing the form. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Application.DoEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx), but [be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/825024) [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115410/825024):

```
private void HideLabelAndShowForm() {
    label1.Hide();
    Application.DoEvents();
    Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the flicker of the old content that you're concerned about, try switch on Double-buffering.

Put this line in the form's constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
```

Comment: More information from the web: http://www.bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.htm and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/DoubleBuffering.aspx

Comment: Josh, as I pointed above, it looks like Desktop Composition feature causes this problem. It works perfectly when it is disabled.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean: the flicker happens with a DWM theme but it doesn't in "Windows Basic"... Weird...

Answer (score 0):

The form's Paint event isn't raised while the form is hidden. It won't paint until you Show() it again. Normally it should be so fast that you don't see it. I think you're just seeing a delay in windows. Your machine may be underpowered for desktop composition.

Other thoughts:

- Your application has a very busy background thread.
- Your form is procesing a lot of messages before it gets to the repaint.
- Your form has too many controls.
- Your computer is very busy with other processes.
- Your computer is just really slow.

Things to try:

- Make sure the CPU is idle. Look for greedy threads/processes.
- Check for things causing your form to have a bazillion messages to process.
- Simplify the form if it has a lot of controls.
- Update graphics driver.
- Get faster computer.

Comment: LOL. I like these especially: "Update graphics driver. Get faster computer". Should I prevent installing my single-label-on-a-single-form program for users not having Core i7?

Comment: Am I supposed to read your mind? You said nothing about your computer or your program. I made no assumptions; I'm just trying to make potentially helpful suggestions. If you want more targeted advice, write a more detailed question. Oh, and you're welcome. I'm so glad I spent the time trying to help you.

Comment: "The form's Paint event isn't raised while the form is hidden" - is there any documentation available for this

Answer (score 0):

```
myForm.Opacity = 0.0F;
myForm.Show();
myForm.Opacity = 1.0F;
```